# Understanding the Reader monad

Tags: haskell, monads, purescript, state-monad, reader-monad

I'm reading *PureScript by Example* and got to the part introducing the Reader monad. The example goes like this:

```
createUser :: Reader Permissions (Maybe User)
createUser = do
  permissions <- ask
  if hasPermission "admin" permissions
    then map Just newUser
    else pure Nothing
```

The confusing part for me is the `ask` function. The signature is:

```
ask   :: forall r. Reader r r
```

It appears as if it creates a Reader out of thin air

When I was reading about the `State` monad, it had the same concept with its `get` function. And the text explained:

*the state is implemented as a function argument hidden by the State monad’s data constructor, so there is no explicit reference to pass around.*

I'm guessing this is the key, and the same thing is happening here with the Reader, but I don't understand how it works...

When the above example is run via `runReader`, how does the provided value suddenly appear as a result of `ask`? The Haskell docs for `ask` say: *Retrieves the monad environment.* But my confusion is *from where*? The way I see it, a value gets passed to `runReader`, gets stored *somewhere*, and to get it - you call `ask`... but that makes no sense.

While the example is PureScript, I'm guessing any Haskell-literate person would also be able to answer, hence the Haskell tag.

Comment: `Reader a b` is a wrapper around `a -> b`. So, `ask :: forall a. Reader a a` is ultimately just a value of type `forall a. a -> a`, with a wrapper around it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't have a PureScript environment around currently, so I'll try to answer from a Haskell perspective, and hope it helps.

A *Reader* is really only a 'wrapper' around a function, so when you get a `Reader r r`, you really only get a reader from `r` to `r`; in other words, a function `r -> r`.

You *can* summon functions out of thin air, because, if you're a Platonist, I suppose they always exist...

When you use `do` notation, you're 'inside the monad', so the context `r` is implicit. In other words, you call a function that returns the `r` value, and when you use the `<-` arrow, you simply get that context.

Comment: Upvoted. Probably worth nothing that the way to summon such an `r -> r` function from thin air is to utter the incantation `id`. (And `id` is the _only_ such function, thanks to parametricity.)

Comment: Ok, so in my case the Reader is a wrapper around Permissions -> Maybe User. When I run `runReader createUser permissions`, how does `ask` in the body of `createUser` know to return the same `permissions` I passed to `runReader`? I'm sure the question is downright nonsensical as I'm looking at this all wrong... But please try helping me unbend my brain.

Comment: @kaqqao The type `Reader Permissions (Maybe User)` is just a 'wrapper' over `Permissions -> (Maybe User)`, so your entire `createUser` 'value' is really a function (but functions are values, so that's cool). When you call `runReader`, you must pass not only `createUser`, but also a value for `r` - in this case a `Permissions` value. `runReader` then calls the wrapped function with the `Permissions` value you passed it. HTH.

Comment: @MarkSeemann Aah, I see. `runReader` effectively sets the state/environment on the Reader instance before invoking the function inside it. (Not sure how good is my terminology) It finally makes sense. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Why should someone disguise the information flow within a composition of pure functions with the monad machinery? Only to abstract from some arguments? Isn't that too high a price?

Comment: @ftor I don't think the point of the `Reader` monad is to *disguise* anything. The `Reader` monad exists, mathematically, so it might as well also exist in the Haskell/TypeScript API. This enables you to use a reader (i.e. a pure function) with all functions that operate on monads. (e.g. `mapM`, `sequence`, and so on...). The motivation isn't to hide anything, but to give you *options* for composition.

Answer (score 4):

You can convince yourself that it works by performing a few substitutions. First look at the signature of `createUser`. Let's "unroll" the definition of `Reader`:

```
createUser :: Reader Permissions (Maybe User)
{- definition of Reader -}
createUser :: ReaderT Permissions Identity (Maybe User)
```

The `ReaderT` type only has one data constructor: `ReaderT (r -> m a)`, which means `createUser` is a term that evaluates to a value of type `ReaderT (Permissions -> Identity (Maybe User))`. As you can see, it is just a function tagged with `ReaderT`. It does not have to create anything out of thin air, but will receive the value of type `Permissions` when that function is called.

Now let's look at the line you are having trouble with. You know that the `do` notation is just syntactic sugar, and the expression:

```
do permissions <- ask
   if hasPermission "admin" permissions
     then map Just newUser
     else pure Nothing
```

desugars to

```
ask >>= \permissions -> 
  if hasPermission "admin" permissions
  then map Just newUser
  else pure Nothing
```

To understand what this does, you will have to lookup the definition of `ask`, `>>=` and `pure` for `ReaderT`. Let's perform another round of substitutions:

```
ask >>= \permissions -> ...
{- definition of ask for ReaderT -}
ReaderT pure >>= \permissions -> ...
{- definition of >>= for ReaderT -}
ReaderT \r ->
  pure r >>= \a -> case (\permissions -> ...) a of ReaderT f -> f r
{- function application -}
ReaderT \r ->
  pure r >>= \a -> 
    case (if hasPermission "admin" a
          then map Just newUser
          else pure Nothing) of ReaderT f -> f r
{- definition of pure for Identity -}
ReaderT \r ->
  Identity r >>= \a -> 
    case (if hasPermission "admin" a
          then map Just newUser
          else pure Nothing) of ReaderT f -> f r
{- definition of >>= for Identity -}
ReaderT \r ->
  (\a -> 
    case (if hasPermission "admin" a
          then map Just newUser
          else pure Nothing) of ReaderT f -> f r) r
{- function application -}
ReaderT \r ->
  case (if hasPermission "admin" r
        then map Just newUser
        else pure Nothing) of ReaderT f -> f r
```

As you can see, `createUser` is clearly just a function wrapped by `ReaderT` that threads a value (the "environment") through your expressions. `runReader` unwraps the function and calls it with the provided argument:

```
runReader :: forall r a. Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader (ReaderT f) r = f r
```

Answer (score 0):

The partial function type `(->) r` is a functor i.e. `r->a` is a container for any type `a` (a `List a` of size two is equivalent to a function `Bool->a`) . Moreover, it is also a monad

```
instance Monad ((->) r) where
    f >>= k = \ r -> k (f r) r
```

It satisfies the `MonadReader` type class and is called the simple reader monad and might be given the type synonym `Reader r`.

`ask` returns this monad `(->) r) r` applied to the same type `r`, which we then can bind.

Understand the partial function type `(->) r` better.